# How to add files to a list after order by its name?

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, version

I am selecting all files in a folder and add all files names into to 2 lists. `xmlFilePath` and `listVersion`

As a example my files names are like below

```
1.8.1

1.8.2

1.10.0

1.10.1
```

but following code add its name as below.

```
1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.8.1, 1.8.2
```

I want to change its order as below (Order by its name)

```
1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.10.0, 1.10.1,
```

How can I achieve this requirement ?

```
FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = folderDlg.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath);
    lblFolder.Text = "Folder : " + folderDlg.SelectedPath;
    lblFiles.Text = "No of Xml Found : " + files.Length.ToString();

    try
    {
        foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath))
        {
            xmlFilePath.Add(filePath);
        }

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            listVersion.Add(fileName);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        lbl_notifications.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: these numbers look like semantic version number, to order by using semver have a look at [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106660/convert-an-object-to-an-ordered-by-semver-markdown-list).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is it's sorting the name as text, without respect to the numeric value of the items. In text, a "1" is less than an "8", and it doesn't matter that the "1" is followed by a "0".

Do this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath);
files = files.OrderBy(f => int.Parse(f.Split(".")[0]))
              .ThenBy(f => int.Parse(f.Split(".")[1]))
              .ThenBy(f => int.Parse(f.Split(".")[2])).ToArray();
```

You can improve on this further by creating a `.Select()` projection at the beginning that includes the filename and split parts, so that you don't have to keep re-Split()-ing the same string, but this should at least work.

Answer (score 1):

If file names are actually *versions* sort them as versions:

```
  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath);

  Array.Sort(files, (left, right) => 
    new Version(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(left)).CompareTo(
    new Version(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(right))));
```

**Edit:** in *general case*, e.g. for names like `"v_1.2.4 bla-bla-bla 5.6.7"` you can use `StrCmpLogicalW` function (As *File Explorer* does) or its analogue

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string x, string y);
...

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath);

Array.Sort(files, (left, right) => StrCmpLogicalW(
  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(left),
  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(right)));
```

Comment: Yes.. this is really working. if I use file name as "v_1.8.1" it gives an error called "Input string was not in a correct format."

How can I use this solution for that kind of  files names ?

Comment: @Sachith - If your file names start with `"v_"` then you should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: @Sachith: in general case I suggest using `StrCmpLogicalW` function (or its analogue). See my edit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are struggling with strings representing versions.

You can convert them to version and sort them.

```
var sortedVersions = files.Select(x => new Version(x)).OrderBy(x => x);
```

Now you can use the `sortedVersions` or convert it back to an array of strings.

```
files = sortedVersions.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

You can take a look at [Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) class and use it if it fits better. Working with strings are risky and you can reduce this risk by using appropriate data type.

If file names start by "v_" then you can modify the code above and handle it.

```
var sortedVersions = files.Select(x => new Version(x.Substring(2))).OrderBy(x => x);
files = sortedVersions.Select(x => "v_" + x.ToString()).ToArray();
```